# BackgroundWorker never does anything?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

This is the code that I am trying to execute, but stepping through my code I never see any progress indicated or updated on my windows form showing `progressbar1`.  This is my 1st attempt in getting a background worker to function properly, and all I have is a windows form with one button on it and this is all of the code involved in the project.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int i = 0;

     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        ReadySteadyGo();
        worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
        FinalizeAndFinish();
        worker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Text = "Done!";
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
    }

    private void ReadySteadyGo()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100000);
    }
    private void FinalizeAndFinish()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say Thread.Sleep you realize you are pausing the background worker thread right? It's not like you are starting a thread here where you have to call sleep to context switch. Let me know if I didn't get it right.

Comment: That's accurate, it doesn't do anything.  Sleeping is not useful.  Nor can you see it doing anything, there's no point to assigning the ProgressBar.Text property since it doesn't display text.  Set Value instead.

Comment: The answer from Vincent is what I was getting to. Let us know if you understand his point and still can't get desired behavior.

Comment: The Thread.Sleep was just so I didn't clutter the entire question with lengthy code.  See my edit...

Comment: @HansPassant I overlooked that and incorporated it into my answer,  hope you don't mind.  Also in recent versions of Visual Studio that property is completely hidden by the design tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your example in Visual Studio and am hitting a breakpoint in backgroundWorker1_DoWork so the multi-threading is working properly, you just need to do proper processing?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Comment: You are correct.  The thread.sleep was just so I would not clutter the post with code.  I am actually not getting any progress indicated on my progressbar after ReadySteadyGo() is left and FInalizeandFinish()

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are using Thread.Sleep() to simulate a long-running operation.  There are a few things you should consider based on your code example:

When the `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` is executed, it starts working on another thread.  Thus, if you are debugging interactively and you have not set a breakpoint in the `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` method, you are not likely to see this code execute.

When the `Thread.Sleep(100000)` executes, it essentially means that the background worker will pause for **100 seconds** - so you need to make sure you are waiting at least that long to see the UI updated.

Also, as per Hans Passant's comment, consider the following:

> Nor can you see it doing anything, there's no point to assigning the
>   `ProgressBar.Text` property since it doesn't display text. Set `Value`
>   instead.